# Nginx hanging on audio file request

Tags: nginx

I'm having the most bizarre issue with nginx.

After upgrading from `1.6.3` to `1.12.2` on RHEL 7.2, requests for audio files are just hanging:

```
Connecting to mydomain [...] ... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

In my nginx `access.log`, I'm seeing a `200` status:

```
"GET /media/Example.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 200 105243 "-" "Wget/1.19.4 (linux-gnu)" "-"
```

If I request an MP4 file in the same directory, with the same permissions, it works just fine. I've tried MP4s that are both larger and smaller than my MP3 file: they work just fine.

CSS/JS/images also work fine.

If I comment out the `MP3` mime type in `/etc/nginx/mime.types`, and then request `/media/Example.mp3`, it works just fine (!!!).

I added the `ogg` mime type to see if this was somehow related to just audio, and indeed, OGG files fail in the same way as MP3s.

I've set up debug logging, and everything looks normal for an MP3 request.

I've disabled SELinux, checked the permissions on the files, parent folders, etc. and confirmed that there is not a problem with the actual MP3 file.

I've tried turning sendfile off.

I can't undo this YUM transaction; it looks like there was a security issue with that version of nginx, and it is no longer available.

I've searched around online, but can't find any related reports. Does anyone have any thoughts/suggestions?

**EDIT**

When I set the `Accept` header and try to connect, `curl` output looks like:

```
*   Trying my.ipaddress...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to my.host (my.ipaddress) port 80 (#0)
> GET /media/Example.mp3 HTTP/1.1
> Host: my.host  
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0 
> Accept: audio/mpeg
>
```

And then it just hangs...

Comment: Can you show us what's actually in `mime.types`?

Comment: @Brad, Sure, see https://gist.github.com/kardeiz/dbbb056c320702c2f6ebfb49187b4bff.

Comment: How do you know this is an nginx issue?  Did you rule out firewall, or any other updates in the system?  Does this happen both locally, as well as over the network?  What happens when you let the connection stay?  Or when you terminate it?  Logs?

Comment: @cnst Thanks for the questions. I should have mentioned that I tried it locally, like `curl -H 'Host: mysite.com' http://localhost/media/Example.mp3`. I let the connection stay for at least 10 minutes, and it just hangs.

Comment: Do you have any nginx module/configuration that is trying to handle that mime type?

Comment: @pbacterio No, my static file handling is just with `root /path/to/files` and I just have `nginx` and `nginx-filesystem` and the nginx modules from `nginx-all-modules` installed.

Comment: @JacobBrown, TBH, you might want to see if you can reproduce this with the official binaries from nginx.org, http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html

Comment: What a `curl -H 'accept: audio/mpeg'  -v http://your.server/media/Example.mp3` return ?

Comment: @wargre It just hangs. If I comment out the `mp3` mime type as noted above, it downloads as expected. I tried both `accept: audio/mpeg` and `Accept: audio/mpeg`.

Comment: @JacobBrown it hang before sending response header or after ?

Comment: @wargre, before. I've updated my post with curl output of that command.

Comment: you never setup an additional module like rtmp or hls ?  You do not have anything specific in your config file ?  (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf  and in /etc/nginx/conf.d/* )

Comment: @wargre No, I don't have any other modules (except `nginx-all-modules`), and my `nginx.conf` is unchanged, except that I commented out the default server block.